# How to explain embedded message binary wire format of protocol buffer?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to understand protocol buffer encoding method, when translating message to binary(or hexadecimal) format, I can't understand how the embedded message is encoded.

I guess maybe it's related to memory address, but I can't find the accurate relationship.

Here is what i've done.

Step 1: I defined two messages in `test.proto` file,

```
syntax = "proto3";
package proto_test;

message Education {
    string college = 1;
}

message Person {
    int32 age = 1;
    string name = 2;
    Education edu = 3;
}
```

Step 2: And then I generated some `go` code,

```
protoc --go_out=. test.proto
```

Step 3: Then I check the encoded format of the message,

```golang
p := proto_test.Person{
    Age:  666,
    Name: "Tom",
    Edu: &proto_test.Education{
        College: "SOMEWHERE",
    },
}
var b []byte
out, err := p.XXX_Marshal(b, true)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("fail to marshal with error: ", err)
}
fmt.Printf("hexadecimal format:% x \n", out)
fmt.Printf("binary format:% b \n", out)
```

which outputs,

```sh
hexadecimal format:08 9a 05 12 03 54 6f 6d 1a fd 96 d1 08 0a 09 53 4f 4d 45 57 48 45 52 45 
binary format:[ 1000  10011010  101  10010  11  1010100  1101111  1101101  11010  11111101  10010110  11010001  1000  1010  1001  1010011  1001111  1001101  1000101  1010111  1001000  1000101  1010010  1000101]
```

what I understand is ,

```sh
08                         - int32 wire type with tag number 1
9a 05                      - Varints for 666
12                         - string wire type with tag number 2
03                         - length delimited which is 3 byte
54 6f 6d                   - ascii for "TOM"
1a                         - embedded message wire type with tag number 3
fd 96 d1 08                - ? (here is what I don't understand)
0a                         - string wire type with tag number 1
09                         - length delimited which is 9 byte
53 4f 4d 45 57 48 45 52 45 - ascii for "SOMEWHERE"
```

What does `fd 96 d1 08` stands for?
It seems like that `d1 08` always be there, but `fd 96` sometimes change, don't know why. Thanks for answering :)

---

**Add**

I debugged the marshal process and reported a bug [here](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/863).

Comment: Tip: http://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode - stick in your hex, and it'll explain every byte

Comment: also: I don't think your data is valid - so, yeah, I'm kinda with you here... is it possible you've corrupted the data and aren't giving the true hex? In particular, by using string functions? FWIW: fd 96 d1 08 in this context specifies that the length of the sub-message is 18107261, which is very wrong

Comment: @ Marc Gravell good work

Answer (score 2):

At that location I/you would expect the number of bytes in the embedded message.

I have repeated your experiment in Python.

```
msg = Person()
msg.age = 666
msg.name = "Tom"
msg.edu.college = "SOMEWHERE"
```

I got a different result, the one I would expect. A varint stating the size of the embedded message.

```
0x08
0x9A, 0x05
0x12
0x03
0x54 0x6F 0x6D
0x1A 
0x0B                        <- Equals to 11 decimal.
0x0A
0x09
0x53 0x4F 0x4D 0x45 0x57 0x48 0x45 0x52 0x45
```

Next I deserialized your bytes:

```
msg2 = Person()
str = bytearray(b'\x08\x9a\x05\x12\x03\x54\x6f\x6d\x1a\xfd\x96\xd1\x08\x0a\x09\x53\x4f\x4d\x45\x57\x48\x45\x52\x45')
msg2.ParseFromString(str)
print(msg2)
```

The result of this is perfect:

```
age: 666
name: "Tom"
edu {
  college: "SOMEWHERE"
}
```

The conclusion I come to is that there are some different ways of encoding in Protobuf. I do not know what is done in this case but I know the example of a negative 32 bit varint. A positive varint is encoded in five bytes, a negative value is cast as a 64 bit value and encoded to ten bytes.

Comment: @QiankunZhang I forgot to mention you could try to deserilize the byte array this python code generated and see if you get a valid massage. I think it will.

Comment: "The conclusion I come to is that there are some different ways of encoding in Protobuf" - well, that's *slightly true*, but in this case I think the problem is that the hex shown is corrupt, presumably something to do with printf; the hex shown in the question *simply isn't valid protobuf*

Comment: @MarcGravell Would that mean that when I deserialize the byte array of Qiankun the code would skip the invalid parts? I did get a valid message out of it. Is there a mechanism to deduct the length of a nested message even if the length is invalid?

Comment: I'm very confused as to how any compliant reader would parse that; it is stating that the sub-message is 18107261 bytes long; most readers will reject that when they find 18107250 missing bytes. It is possible that the Python one (i.e. the one you're using) just reads to the end, but IMO this would be a bug in that implementation!

Comment: @MarcGravell I do not understand this either. To try your suggestion that it just reads to the end of the array I have added some random characters. Just one extra character will already generate an error.

Comment: I would expect it to, since 1 byte by itself is never valid; I'm wondering if it is the "sub-message is incomplete, but stream ended while at a valid break-point" is the scenario that isn't detected. Try adding hex `10 00` (this is "field 2, varint, value 0")

Comment: Yes of course! I forgot about that. It works as expected.

Comment: @Bart Thanks for answering, i debug the marshal process and reported a bug [here](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/863), it seems like that it's an implementation issue.

Comment: why does here record `11` ?  couldn't the binary be decoded without the `11`?